# Spring boot Jersey and Eureka maven starters integration

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud, jsr311

I'm trying to use both `spring-cloud-starter-eureka (Brixton.M2)` and `spring-boot-starter-jersey` maven dependencies in a Spring boot Project (1.3.0.RC1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

with a simple Jersey controller

```
@Path("/test")
@Component
public class TestController {

    @GET
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }

}
```

but i have this error when i try to the rest endpoint.

```
2015-11-10 10:12:24.177  WARN 1469 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors     : The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Cannot create new registration for component type class org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent$WebComponentBinder: Existing previous registration found for the type.

2015-11-10 10:12:24.177 ERROR 1469 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:331) ~[jersey-server-2.22.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:837) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:694) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:305) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:180) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
```

I have found a by-pass which consist of excluding the `jsr-311` maven dependencies from the `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` but i don't know if it's the better solution and if this trick will break other things at runtime.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Eureka client uses jersey. What you did is likely the only solution until eureka 2. You may very well break something.